# How to fix my code in next js 13 because, make my browser crash

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

[image: crash]

I want to use localstorage in my next js 13 project, but why does it make my browser lag/crash. the code is like this

```
const handleAddBookmark = (data: any, id: number) => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
         const bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') || '[]');
         const newBookmark = data?.verses?.find((verse: any) => verse.number.inQuran === id);
         if (newBookmark) {
            const {
               number: { inSurah, inQuran },
            } = newBookmark;
            const isDuplicate = bookmarks.some((bookmark: any) => bookmark.number_id === inQuran);
            if (!isDuplicate) {
               bookmarks.push({
                  numberSurah: data?.number,
                  name: data?.name,
                  numberInQuran: inQuran,
                  numberInSurah: inSurah,
               });
               localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
               window.dispatchEvent(new Event('bookmarks'));
            }
         }
      }
   };

   const handleRemoveBookmark = (number: number) => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
         const bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') || '[]');
         const newBookmarks = bookmarks
            .filter((bookmark: any) => bookmark.numberInQuran !== number)
            .map((bookmark: any) => ({ ...bookmark }));
         localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(newBookmarks));
         window.dispatchEvent(new Event('bookmarks'));
      }
   };

   const handleBookmarkClick = (item: any, number: number) => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
         const bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') || '[]');
         const isSaved = bookmarks.some((bookmark: any) => bookmark.numberInQuran === number);
         if (isSaved) {
            handleRemoveBookmark(number);
         } else {
            handleAddBookmark(item, number);
         }
      }
   };
```

I don't know what causes it because when I don't use these components it's safe, but when I use them it actually crashes my laptop
and when I deploy it doesn't show any error, but when I open the page it shows error 504

Comment: Does it happens when you remove the dispatch event in those methods? What is listening to those events?

Comment: it happens when I use the component and run it, my browser immediately crashes and an error appears like the picture above, even though I haven't clicked the onClick function

Comment: this is so annoying, I'm also experiencing crashes but the worst thing is browser console has no errors neither has the vscode console, at least in Next 12 it was either a client side error and it appeared in the console or a backend issue and it appeared in vscode